# Lift Vim undo-tree file size limit?

Tags: vim

Looks like my vim undofiles only track the last 500KB or so of changes. At the bottom of my gundo panel it goes from edit revision 1774 to 0 (the total number of revisions to the file is 2776). While this indicates the entire history may exceed 1MB, that is very acceptable since this is several days' worth of work (which, still not being complete, couldn't be inserted into the revision control system per my company's code check-in policies).

Is there a way to make it keep more history in vim's undotree? Not that it'll be particularly easy or fun to wade through it all, but not having it throw it away would be nice.

Comment: Using version control is the obvious solution, unless you want to keep track of all your typos.

Comment: Yes. I have been retroactively loading up the vim revisions and inserting them into a git repo. We use p4 because the codebase is too big and interconnected for git to deal with it effectively, but tracking individual files manually using git works very well

Comment: Take a look at `:h undolevels`

Comment: yep that's gotta be it, on account of 2776 and 1774 (i must have made 2 phantom edits). Thanks for the tip! comments need a "make this an answer" button.

Comment: "this is several days' worth of work (which, still not being complete, couldn't be inserted into the revision control system)." Isn't that what branching is for?

Comment: @KyleStrand Yeah, couldn't use git there, though. Codebase too large to fit in git. And I can't really branch with perforce. Maybe make a few shelvelists. But that sucks and is not as nice as a git branch. My actual solution to things like that was to run git on top of p4.

Comment: That's...odd, since technically Git has no size limits, though I suppose I can imagine a project becoming increasingly unwieldy in Git. Why can't you branch in p4? It looks like you should be able to, and in fact, the first example under "when to branch" here looks almost identical to your situation: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/06_codemgmt.html

Comment: Well that wasn't a workflow that existed at our operation, so I couldn't do that. Merging and branching on centralized VCS's are never worth the trouble for local changes of this sort, in my experience. But you are right at the end of the day, relying on Vim to track history is not a good way to go. However, surely you must agree that it being capable of doing it is an admirable property for an editor to have.

Comment: As for Git having no file size limits, the fact that hashing >1GB of code takes a few minutes makes it impractical. It's not impractical if the codebase is separated sanely, but that ship obviously had sailed. Perforce's new stuff that incorporates Git into the system sounds like a promising direction for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `:h undolevels`. Set it to a really large number.

Copied below for convenience.

```
                                                'undolevels' 'ul'
'undolevels' 'ul'       number  (default 100, 1000 for Unix, VMS,
                                                Win32 and OS/2)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
        Maximum number of changes that can be undone.  Since undo information
        is kept in memory, higher numbers will cause more memory to be used
        (nevertheless, a single change can use an unlimited amount of memory).
        Set to 0 for Vi compatibility: One level of undo and "u" undoes
        itself: 
                set ul=0
        But you can also get Vi compatibility by including the 'u' flag in
        'cpoptions', and still be able to use CTRL-R to repeat undo.
        Also see undo-two-ways.
        Set to a negative number for no undo at all: 
                set ul=-1
        This helps when you run out of memory for a single change.
        Also see clear-undo.
```

Comment: I'm confused, the default value for 'undolevels' is 100 or 1000?

Comment: @Chad vim supports a lot of operating systems some with less memory than others. I think the default depends on which system it was compiled for.